# install PHP Cassandra driver on Heroku

Tags: php, heroku, pear

I'm creating a buildpack to install a PHP extension. 
I would like execute `pecl install cassandra`.

%customPath%/.apt/usr/bin/pecl: 28: exec: /usr/bin/php: not found

If I execute `which php`, the php path is %customPath%/.apt/usr/bin/php
And I can't execute `pear config-set …` (bin_dir or php_dir), I have the same error.

Do you know how change the first default php_bin path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very good news! 
Now there is an optional extension for that: 
https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/910